# Shouldn't we use using blocks with Unity3D's WWW class (implements IDisposable)?

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I am wondering if there is any good reason why in the Unity3D documentation in this example: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-texture.html there is no using-block around the WWW instance.

The WWW class implements IDisposable, so shouldn't the code be like that:

```
IEnumerator Start() 
{
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
    {
        yield return www;
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DonA No - it's right, but it's confusing - the default view is javascript, not C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the `WWW` class does implement IDisposable, it would be better if the sample was written as you've shown.

I suspect the main issue was that the same C# is likely a port of the Javascript version, which doesn't have `using` as an option.

Comment: Well, but the JavaScript version has the Dispose() method, hasn't it? Shouldn't the Dispose() method be explicitly called in the JavaScript version? Or how are resources freed if Dispose() is not called?

Comment: @j00hi Most likely, it would be a good practice to call it, but it should get handled (in either case) if you don't eventually.